# Nativescript style limitations

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I started to develop a mobile app using nativescript, everything was going well until I realized I cant customize the style as I want. Just for example I cant set the border to a button like `border-width: 1 0 0 1`.
There is a way to extend the styling behavior? 
I'm considering to start using ionic :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of NativeScrtip version 2.4.0 (the next release), this functionality will be available, which means that you will be able to create a border with

```
border-width:0 2 2 0;
border-color: red;
```

If you want to test it now (before the release of 2.4.0) then remove tns-core-modules and install the @next version.

```
tns plugin remove tns-core-modules
tns plugin add tns-core-modules@next
```

You can also take a look [at this issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/859#issuecomment-247768978) to see what you can do with the new borders implementation

Comment: So glad I missed that borders are in 2.4 now :) awesome stuff

Answer (score 2):

As of right now per side borders are not available with the css subset NativeScript exposes. They are a PITA to do on iOS, the good news is the core team knows this and I believe it's been prioritized in recent weeks. So I expect it will be possible in a release coming up.

With all that said, if you have a specific case you want you can still achieve it with NativeScript but it's not as easy as the css border styling. Just remember the css stylers in NativeScript are being mapped to the native methods/properties to style native components, so it's awesome to be able to use css even though its not 1-1 with the vast css that browsers have, it does get better every release

If you want to do a per side borders right now you can use a stacklayout with a height of 1 and set the background color. So for a 4 sided object you would use a grid layout and put a stack on the first and third row, your component on the middle (2nd) row and then a stack on the first and 3 columns (0 & 1 values). Again, I know it's not ideal but it's just a limitation for now that its not exposed in the css subset for NativeScript. I haven't checked the source or issues for any updates on this in a while but its possible something is being worked on now to enable this functionality. Hope this helps some. If you have some code and need help please share and I can help  more.